# Where is the create method of BelongsTo class?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a general class for uploads.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class File extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
}
```

An ID of `File` model will be specified on each person to serve as the avatar:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Person extends Model
{
    public function avatar()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\File');
    }

    public function putAvatar($file)
    {
        $path = $file->store('avatars');

        // This would work if `avatar()` was a `hasMany()` relation
        $this->avatar()->create([
            'path' => $path,
        ]);
    }
}
```

This doesn't work exactly as intended, but it creates the `File` model in database. Why?

The `$this->avatar()` is an instance of `BelongsTo` and there is no `create` method. I checked the class, the included traits and the `Relation` class that it extends. [Reference here](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsTo.html).

So what's going on, where is the code that creates the new model?

I tried using a `ReflectionMethod` but while `$this->avatar()->create()` works, `new ReflectionMethod($this->avatar(), 'create')` returns a `ReflectionException` with message `Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::create() does not exist`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method for saving entities on belongsTo relationships.  Once the entity is created, you can associate it with the model.

```
$avatar = File::create([...]);
$this->avatar()->associate($avatar)->save();
```

---

To allow querying of relationships, undefined method calls are passed to an Eloquent Builder instance which does have a create method.

All relationships extend the Relation class which defines:

```
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    if (static::hasMacro($method)) {
        return $this->macroCall($method, $parameters);
    }

    $result = $this->query->{$method}(...$parameters);

    if ($result === $this->query) {
        return $this;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: I know that these methods do not exist. The question is - why the `create` method works?

Comment: @Džuris I've added details about this.  You can always use a debugger or backtraces to follow the trail, or just review the class and parent class itself.

Answer (score 0):

The method used for `belongsTo()` should be `save()`, not `created()`. Make sure to pass as an argument your `File` class:

```
$this->avatar()->save(new File([
   'path' => $path,
]));
```

Comment: This throws an exception, there is no such method at all. But the main question is about the fact that I can't find the `create` method in the code either but it somehow works.